# rethinkdb PHP-RQL changes

Tags: php, rethinkdb

I'm using [PHP-RQL](http://danielmewes.github.io/php-rql/) library to work with  RethinkDB,
i need to get changes when new data inserted.
but i'm getting PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RqlDriverError:
  Options must be an array.

in api documentation its says:

```
table->changes(array('squash' => true, 'include_states' => false)) → stream
singleSelection->changes(array('squash' => true, 'include_states' => false)) → stream
Return an infinite stream of objects representing changes to a query.
```

Example: Subscribe to the changes on a table.

```
r\table('games')->changes()->run($conn, function($err, $cursor) {
    $cursor->each($console->$log)
})
```

How to subscribe to the changes on a table? This example is doesn't work.

Comment: The example in the API docs is just wrong. Sorry for the confusion. I opened https://github.com/danielmewes/php-rql/issues/108 about that. See below for how it currently works in PHP-RQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP-RQL is fully synchronous at the moment, so you cannot give it a callback.
Instead you get a cursor that you can iterate:

```
$cursor = r\table('games')->changes()->run($conn);
foreach ($update in $cursor) {
    printr($update);
})
```

What are you using for concurrency? Are you using any async framework (React PHP) or multi-threading or anything like that?

There's no native integration into React with PHP-RQL at the moment, though if you're running a thread-enabled version of PHP you can spawn a thread, open a separate connection inside the thread and use the synchronous cursor interface from within there.

Comment: ok thanks you now i understand, i'm using just symfony2. i will try "React PHP" this framework is new for for me.